# I'm having trouble with designing a series of tables

Tags: html, css

The table is in the image attached below.

Can anyone help me out with the html and css to create this? I have been trying for about an hour or two. I cant get a separate border around each table. as well as the spacing. Pretty much everything I'm having trouble with, I don't know CSS yet but my lecturer asked us to try it out.

[Tables I'm having trouble with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaFsP.jpg)

```css
td { "background-color: #D3D3D3;
  }
table {
    border:1 px; solid #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> 
<td> Short title: </td> 
<td> Data Driven Apps I </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add what you have already tried.

Comment: edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste your code

Comment: Sorry about that, Im new to this site hence the way I asked the question was poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the styling with border-spacing and border-collapse and join columns with colspan

**demo**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBEZNb

css:

```
table {
  border-spacing:0 10px;
  border-collapse:separate; 
}

td {
  padding:2px 10px;
  border-top:1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

td.gray {
  background:#ddd
}

td:last-child {
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray">Short Title</td>
    <td colspan="2">Data Driven Apps 1</td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray">Full Title</td>
    <td colspan="2">Data Driven Apps 1</td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray">Attendance</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="gray">Discipline</td>
    <td colspan="2">Databases</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="gray">Coordinator</td>
    <td>Gerry</td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="gray">Department</td>
    <td colspan="2">Information Technology</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="gray">Official Code</td>
     <td>GATB</td>
     <td class="gray">NFQ Level</td>
     <td>08</td>
     <td class="gray">ECTS Credit</td>
     <td>05</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm new to this site, My question was phrased poorly but thanks for that.